# Android Studio View displays differently than on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S5)

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I'm creating an app on android and running into an issue. When I go to edit in Android Studio, all the elements to my app look as intended. I am using a ConstraintLayout and making sure everything is using sp as its units to ensure scaling happens. I have tried to change margin and padding but no matter what I've done, the buttons on my phone display as being smashed together.

Here is how the view is in Android Studio (how I want it to look):
[image: Android Studio View]

Here is how it looks on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S5): [image: My Phone View]

On my phone, the buttons are going into each other, but on my android studio, the buttons have white space between them. How can I modify my code to create my intented image?

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Settings">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:onClick="homeMenu"
        android:text="@string/homeButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculateButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:onClick="programMenu"
        android:text="@string/calculateButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settingsIntroTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/settingsIntroTextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@John Joe answer is good indeed, but when using `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` there is a small danger - if the view width is very long it can mess up the UI. an easy solution would be to constrain both of the button edges to your textView and by doing that your button will get resized accordingly and won't mess up the UI.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/homeButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="return home"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/settingsIntroTextView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.964" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/calculateButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Create program"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/settingsIntroTextView"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.964" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/settingsIntroTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text=" setting page"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Nice solution !

Comment: This fixes the issue I was having, thank you. Can you help me understand more of why I was getting my problem? Anything besides setting the buttons to be constrained between the TextView?

Comment: because  you used `wrap_content` your views will expand according to the view width. If you will add 500dp width image and set the width to `wrap_content` your image will be 500dp width.

Answer (score 2):

Try this answer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="homeMenu"
        android:text="return home"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.964" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculateButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="programMenu"
        android:text="Create program"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/homeButton" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.964"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settingsIntroTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="setting"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is really good, in my answer, I have given my perspective on using `"wrap_content"`. Feel free to look at it, maybe it can give you some extra knowledge (after all stack overflow is a place where you can learn something new any day)